# How can I combine rows in PostgreSQL using Python2.7

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I have data of the following format:

```
|------------------------|
| Product | Color | Year |
|------------------------|
|  Ball   | Blue  | 1999 |
|  Ball   | Blue  | 2000 |
|  Ball   | Blue  | 2001 |
|  Stick  | Green | 1984 |
|  Stick  | Green | 1985 |
|------------------------|
```

How can I convert this into the following:

```
|-----------------------------|
| Product | Color | Year Range|
|-----------------------------|
|  Ball   | Blue  | 1999-2001 |
|  Stick  | Green | 1984-1985 |
|-----------------------------|
```

The data is in a PostgreSQL table and contains 187,000+ rows that desperately need to be consolidated in this fashion. How can I take care of this using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The data is in a PostgreSQL table and contains 187,000+ rows that
>   desperately need to be consolidated in this fashion.

It might desperately need to be consolidated that way for reporting, but it almost certainly does *not* need to be consolidated that way for storage. Step lightly here.

You can get the data in roughly that format just with a `GROUP BY` clause.  (I used "product_color_years" as the table name.)

```
select product, color, min(year), max(year)
from product_color_years
group by product, color
```

To consolidate the years into a single column, use the concatenation operator.

```
select product, color, min(year) || '-' || max(year) year_range
from product_color_years
group by product, color
```

This works only as long as

- there aren't any gaps in the year range, or
- there are gaps, but you don't care.

If there are gaps that you'd like to see reported like this:

```
product  color  year_range
--
Ball     Blue   1999-2001
Ball     Blue   2003-2005
Stick    Mauve  2000, 2010
```

then you're probably better off using a report writer.  (For example, Google "python reports".) The SQL above will report these blue balls as `Ball  Blue  1999-2005`, which might not be what you want.